# How to write variable of activity that contains fragment class from inside current Fragment?

Tags: android-activity, android-viewpager, fragmentmanager

I have an activity with indefinite number of fragments. Inside fragments there is a variable that need to access in the activity to call an intend from activity bar correctly. 
But only the variable of the current fragment is on screen.
This is because the call depends of the fragment you are.
Due to fragment manager creates three fragment at a time can't write a variable calling from inside fragment because i don't know who is the last that writes variable.
Need to identify the fragment is displayed.
I tried from inside to control visibility overriding setUserVisibleHint(boolean b) and write  variable when true but same happends. not guaranteed that the current fragment is the last writting.
I also tried getting the current fragment from activity to call fragment method and get this variable. But is difficult to identify current fragment. I tried this:

```
getsupportFragmentManager()
     .findFragmentByTag("android:switcher:"+R.id.myViewPager+":"+myViewPager.getCurrentItem()).getVariable();
```

But have null Pointer Exception.